# Как сделать чтобы красный блок шел после картинки , а не на ней

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Красный блок лежит на картинке и не могу его опустить.

HTML:

```
     <header>
        <nav class="top_menu">
            <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="main_menu">
                        <ol>
                            <li class="item_menu active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="item_menu"><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                            <li class="item_menu"><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                            <li class="item_menu"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                            <li class="item_menu"><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                            <li class="item_menu"><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                            <li class="item_menu"><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section class="main_banner">
        <div class="text_banner">
            <h1>Welcome to my charity</h1>
            <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting</span><br>
            <button type="button" class="btn">Donate Now</button>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="content">
                <div class="item_1"></div>
                <div class="item_2"></div>
                <div class="item_3"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    padding: 40px 100px;
}
.main_menu ol li a{
    color:#373838;
}
.main_menu {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    margin-left:40px;
}
.main_menu ol{
    list-style-type: none;
}
.main_menu ol li {
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
}
.main_menu a {
    padding: 6px 17px;
}
.main_menu ol li a:hover,
.main_menu ol li a:focus {
    background-color: #9b242d;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.item_menu.active a{
    background-color: #9b242d;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.main_banner {
    background-image: url(img/banner.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.btn {
    padding: 18px 47px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color:#46a651;
    border:1px solid transparent;
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
    margin-top:80px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.text_banner {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:230px;
}
.text_banner h1 {
    font-size: 46px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: "times new roman";
    margin-bottom:24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.text_banner span {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: "times new roman";
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.item_1 {
    width: 500px;
    background-color: red;
    height:370px;

}
.item_2 {
    background-image: url(img/item_1.png);
    height:370px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: none;

}
.item_3 {
    height:370px;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

проблема была в том что объект был прописан с position:absolute; и он перекрывал главную картинку

```
   .content {
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```css
header {
    padding: 40px 100px;
}
.main_menu ol li a{
    color:#373838;
}
.main_menu {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    margin-left:40px;
}
.main_menu ol{
    list-style-type: none;
}
.main_menu ol li {
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
}
.main_menu a {
    padding: 6px 17px;
}
.main_menu ol li a:hover,
.main_menu ol li a:focus {
    background-color: #9b242d;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.item_menu.active a{
    background-color: #9b242d;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.main_banner {
    background-image: url(img/banner.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.btn {
    padding: 18px 47px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color:#46a651;
    border:1px solid transparent;
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
    margin-top:80px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.text_banner {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:230px;
}
.text_banner h1 {
    font-size: 46px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: "times new roman";
    margin-bottom:24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.text_banner span {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: "times new roman";
}
.content {
    width: 100%;
}
.item_1 {
    width: 500px;
    background-color: red;
    height:370px;

}
.item_2 {
    background-image: url(img/item_1.png);
    height:370px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: none;

}
.item_3 {
    height:370px;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <nav class="top_menu">
            <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="main_menu">
                        <ol>
                            <li class="item_menu active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="item_menu"><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                            <li class="item_menu"><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                            <li class="item_menu"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                            <li class="item_menu"><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                            <li class="item_menu"><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                            <li class="item_menu"><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section class="main_banner">
        <div class="text_banner">
            <h1>Welcome to my charity</h1>
            <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting</span><br>
            <button type="button" class="btn">Donate Now</button>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="content">
                <div class="item_1"></div>
                <div class="item_2"></div>
                <div class="item_3"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: А можете ответить более подробно и добавить рабочий пример с вашей правкой?

Comment: проблема была в том что объект был прописан с position:absolute; и он перекрывал главную картинку

Comment: Прекрасно, тёзка, добавьте это в ответ.

Comment: Если убрать position:absolute , то красный блок становится под картинкой и его не видно , а мне надо чтобы он спустился в низ пол картинку

Comment: как мне можно увидеть с картинками ?

Comment: как мне скинуть файл?